# Cygnus docker not able to connect to CartoDB

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to connect a Cygnus deployed using docker to my CartoDB account. The process I follow is to copy a new version of the cartodb_keys.conf file to the container, then stop the container and start it.

The problem that I found is that when Cygnus starts, it somehow removes the API Key from the cartodb_keys.conf file, giving the following error

```
time=2018-02-14T12:41:23.930Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=startAllComponents | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[173] : Starting Sink cartodb-sink
time=2018-02-14T12:41:23.931Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=initializeBackend | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink[284] : [cartodb-sink] Json containing CartoDB API keys has been read: {   "cartodb_keys": [      {         "username": "myuser",         "endpoint": "https://myuser.cartodb.com",         "type": "professional"      }   ]}
time=2018-02-14T12:41:23.939Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=initializeBackend | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink[288] : [cartodb-sink] Json containing CartoDB API keys is syntactically OK
time=2018-02-14T12:41:23.943Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=initializeBackend | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink[343] : [cartodb-sink] Invalid API key entry, key is null or empty. Discarding it.
time=2018-02-14T12:41:23.944Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink[274] : [cartodb-sink] Error while creating the CartoDB persistence backend. Details: All the API key entries were discarded
```

However, the cartodb_keys.conf file is as follows:

```
{
  "cartodb_keys": [
     {
        "username": "myuser",
        "endpoint": "https://myuser.cartodb.com",
        "key":"myapikey",
        "type":"professional"
     }
  ]
}
```

When accessing the container after restarting, the /opt/apache-flume/conf/cartodb_keys.conf file, is as follows:

```
{
   "cartodb_keys": [
      {
         "username": "jmgarciaemergya",
         "endpoint": "https://jmgarciaemergya.cartodb.com",
"key":""
         "type": "professional"
      }
   ]
}
```

Do you have any clue about what can be happening?

Best regards